# ASP.Net - Poor Mans Asynch "Please Wait..." Animation

Tags: asp.net, jquery, postback

I have a page that, thanks to **jQuery** will automatically click the "Run Report" button under certain conditions.  So, when the user goes to the page via the menu, they wait for x seconds and the results are returned.  This works great...

However, I want to add an animation because some users are not aware anything is going on and I also would like to just show a spinner.  The application is not yet "Ajaxified" and may never be.  So I thought of a poor-mans way of doing it.

I have a `div` that has text and an image in it.  That div has a class on that that simply does `display: none;`  The same jQuery that clicks the button I also have it using the `.toggleClass` method to now Show the div.

This works great AND the report runs and eventually returns the data and since at that point the page is refreshed, the div gets hidden again and all is right in the world.

My problem is, the image shows but does not animate.  I tried to put it Before the click hoping that would happen and start its thing Then the click even to start the waiting would occur.

Is there anything I can do to force the Gif to animate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the jQuery ajax method to request the report? If so there is a function built into the standard ajax method.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/webservices/taskHelper.asmx/ArchiveTask",
    data: '{taskId: 5}',
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#spinner").show();
    },
    error: deft.ajaxError,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#spinner").hide();
    }
});
```

The "beforeSend" function will execute when the link is clicked and continue to run until a response is recieved from the server. I use the beforeSend function to display my hidden div containing an animated gif. Works just fine. 
[jQuery ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Sadly no, I can not use your example.  Basically I call the ObjectDataSource's DataBind method to "get" or "reget" the data.  Inside its _Selecting event I am filling in values necessary for the query that get run.  I tried to call it as a WebMethod and that theoretically could work but the WebMethod needs to be Static and that is where it falls apart.  I tried to just enable the spinner as you show above and Then via javascirpt click the button.  I get the same result, the image shows but doesn't spin.

Answer (score 1):

Submitting a form stops all page action, including GIF animations.

The way around this is to post your form to a hidden Iframe. Of course you'll need the iframe to "wake up" the main page and show its content there once the results appear.

Comment: is spot on. Place your animated graphic in a hidden div, and upon the click of the button, have javascript "show" the previously hidden div